# Catan Cities and Knights: Aqueduct and The Robber

Tags: catan-cities-and-knights

If you have the Aqueduct, do you take a resource card if you didn't receive any production due to the fact the robber was on your only producing hex for that turn.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The rules text for Aqueduct is

> If, when the dice are rolled for production, you do not receive any resources or commodities, you may take any one resource of your choice from the bank. You may not, however, use this ability when a "7" is rolled.

I think the first sentence is sufficient evidence: the rule does not care about *why* you do not receive resources (except as qualified by the second sentence), so your case counts too. However, I include the second sentence as additional evidence: it shows they thought about and explicitly listed exceptions. Your case is not listed, so your case is not an exception.